# How to align and join an objects edge to another?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, snapping

I have these two objects and i want to "glue" them togheter in their bottom edges, I have tried my luck with the snapping tool but it seems I'm missing something. Thanks in advance.

[image: those are my two objects]

those are my two objects

[image]

I tried snapping like this

[image]

But the first obj would end up completely merged in the center of the edge